# Google Charts with Android Webview

Tags: android, webview, google-visualization

I am trying to do the typical thing where you load data into a URL string, call google's chart API with all that date, and then Load it into a Webview.

**Question: Does someone have a direct 'right' way to do this?**

I have been messing with this all night.

Here is the main problem:

The webview is set to Fill_Parent.  Meaning I dont really know the exact width and height.  Since google's API requires that you present a width and height, how exactly do I get the webviews width and height so I can send it over?  I tried this solution:

```
final WebView web = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webviewgraph);
    ViewTreeObserver tree = web.getViewTreeObserver();
    tree.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() 
        {...code continues
```

And things seem to be in order, but when I call web.getWidth(), web.getDrawingBounds(), or web.getMeasuredWidth(), I am always returned MORE than what the screen actually holds.  Right now I am solving this issue by subtracting a constant offset of 136 pixels... but alas, this is NOT consistent with all devices.

Does someone know either the "correct" way to use google map API's with a fluid webview?  Or perhaps does someone know how to get the actual correct width and height of a view?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I changed my code such that now I am using a custom webview that overrides the OnSizeChanged event.  The width and height that are returned are ... unfortunately still the same... Just too large.

**UPDATE**
After analyzing the width and height more, I came up with this:

```
int w = (int)((float)width * .667f);
int h = (int)((float)height * .667f);
```

So far this is working on the devices I am testing on.  Why would the width and height be returning 1/3 MORE than the actual width? I have no idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't had time to double check this, but I find it highly likely that your 0.667f is related to the fact that the webview is scaled according to the density of your devices.

According to 
http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity
*"the high-density device shows the web page with a default scale factor that is 1.5 times larger than the actual pixel resolution, to match the target density"*

You need to find the target density use and use it as the scale:

```
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

// Your code:
int w = (int)(width / scale);
int h = (int)(height / scale);
```

I'm not too well read on the subject, but I think that you can prevent the scaling using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

but don't take my word for it. Also, I'm not sure from which API level the viewport is valid.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try using the callback [OnSizeChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)() ? . They say its called after rendering the view so it should hold information about the actual size if the WebView.

Comment: hmmm you mean extending the webview class and overriding the onSizeChanged event?  I could give that a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's working but the width and the height returned are the same as before... too large in both dimensions.

Comment: Hey followed your solution and the app was working for all devices until my friend tested on HTC wildfire which has 240*320 px display.
On his device the getWidth of webview returns the correct size, not the 1/3rd more than the actual :( removed multiplication by 0.667f and the webview looks good as ever on his device.. but with this setting it renders a lot bigger on my xperia x10 or galaxy.. Did you find the correct soultion for this?

Comment: No, unfortunately this is my current solution.  I really do think it's an Android Bug that should probably be submitted. :P